# Where did du/8x go for the integral?

Tags: integration, substitution

Ok, I have a very simple question. I am trying to do the following integral by substitution.
$$
\int \frac{x}{{ \left(4x^2 + 1\right)}^5 }dx
$$

Putting it into an online solver, they substitute $u= 4x^2 + 1$ so they get $dx = \frac{1}{8x} du$. In the next step, they write
$$
\frac{1}{8} \int \frac{1}{u^5} du
$$
So my question is what happens to $x$ (as is $ \frac{1}{8x}$) as in in this step?

Comment: It canceled with the $x$ in the numerator

Comment: Thanks a lot, no idea how i didn't see that.

Comment: It would have looked better to write $x \, dx = \tfrac18 du$ (not mixing new and old variables).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\int \frac{x}{u^5}*\frac{1}{8x}du$$ x in the numerator cancels out with x in the denominator